# Jquery.ajax load data from html using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have some problems loading input field from html using php. I am using jQuery Ajax `$.post` function to send my data from input filed to php file in order to do the query from the database.

I have fixed the code. Code below is working perfectly.

Here is the html from my main page

```
<input class="detail" maxlength="60" name="detail" placeholder="Type to search">
<button class="searchbtn" name="search">Search</button>
```

and this is the jQuery Ajax part

```
$(".searchbtn").click(function(e) {
    makeAjaxRequest();  
});

function makeAjaxRequest(){
var input = $(".detail").val(); 
$.post("search.php",{detail:input},function(data,status){
        $('#resultTable tbody').html(data);

});
```

Then last part is the php file (search.php)

```
if (isset($_POST['detail'])) {
    $data = $_POST['detail'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ".%data; 
$result = $conn->query($query) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $rows[] = $row;
}
}
```

Now it worked perfectly.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extracting `$_POST['detail']` on your server side page, but while sending on client side, you are sending like this, `$.post("search.php",input`.

Data should be sent data as PlainObject or string. I mean, every POST data should have some index to get referenced on the other end.

Since you are extracting with index `detail`, add `detail` on following like:

```
$.post("search.php",{detail:input},function(data,status){
```

See  :     [jQuery : $.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

currently you're just sending a string with no key/value. You need to send a key/value pair as your data parameter, either as a string or an object (object is safer, as it'l get automatically urlencoded)

```
$.post("search.php",{detail:input},function(data,status){
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
function makeAjaxRequest(){
    var input = $(".detail").val(); 
    $.post("search.php",
        {detail: input},
        function(data,status){
            $('#resultTable tbody').html(data);

    });
}
```